# Embedded Linux Distribution for thin client

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, thin-client

I have a WYSE j400 thin client and I want to experiment with different functions for it. It currently has a 1ghz VIA CPU, 1gig of SDRAM and a 512mb flash IDE.

Is there a recommended embedded Linux distributions that will operate with the specifications above and will fit on that flash with room to spare, or are there any embedded Linux distributions targeted to repurposing thin clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking at [Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.org/) for a while for similar use case, it is very nice. The configuration you described is even a bit more than what it requires. And it is a full fledged desktop solution.

I couldn't find a "Puppy Linux requirements" page, but here is what I found scattered around:

- runs with as low as 64MB of RAM fine
- For HDD installs: the target installation partition has to have ≥350MB free space available
- CPU as low as 333MHz confirmed

The Puppy is a surprisingly complete little Linux, totally fit for reusing these kinds of computers.